# I want to handle denying permission error

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Flutter_blue package
When I deny access to bluetooth there is an error I can't handle. This is what shows:

[image]

This is how my code looks like:

```
 scan() {
    // Start scanning
    try {
      blue.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4));
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
}
```

I want to handle denying permission to bluetooth. Can't handle exception error

Answer (score 0):

If you use method `startScan` which returns a `Future` you can use [`catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/Future/catchError.html) method on `Future` class:

```
blue.startScan().catchError((error) {
  // handle errors here
});
```

If you use method `scan` which returns a `Stream` you can handle errors specifying `onError` parameter when calling `listen` method:

```
blue.scan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4)).listen((event) {
  // here comes data
}, onError: (Object error){
  // handle an error here
});
```

You can read more about the `listen` method [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/Stream/listen.html).

OR

You can use [`handleError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-async/Stream/handleError.html) method on `Stream` object:

```
blue.scan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 4))
  .handleError((error) => print('Exception caught for $error')) // handle the error
  .listen((event) {
    // here comes data
  });
```

Comment: listen and handleError methods not defined

Comment: @helloitsme3 right, you can use `blue.scan()` to handle errors.

Comment: @helloitsme3 have you checked my answer? I've edited it for your use case